# React native: Unable to resolve "@ant-design/icons-react-native/fonts/antoutline.ttf"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a little problem with React Native, I'm using the ant design RN for UI components (https://rn.mobile.ant.design/)
But when i tried to load the ant design fonts , an error appeared. It sayed

> "Unable to resolve
>   "@ant-design/icons-react-native/fonts/antoutline.ttf" from "App.js"

.

the code :

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      antoutline: require("@ant-design/icons-react- 
            native/fonts/antoutline.ttf")
     })
  }
```

Package.json

```
{
"main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
"scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons-react-native": "^1.0.2",
    "@ant-design/react-native": "^3.1.3",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0"
},
"private": true
```

}

I'm using Expo as a cli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you are trying to use a dependency that requires linking of native code.

From their [installation](https://rn.mobile.ant.design/docs/react/introduce) instructions you can see the following:

```
react-native link @ant-design/icons-react-native
```

As your app is made with Expo, and the native code is abstracted away from you, it is not possible to use the link command.

---

Your options are:

1. Eject your Expo project using `expo eject`. This will give you full access to the native code. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/).
2. Expo comes with AntDesign icons built in, you can access them using `@expo/vector-icons`. There is more in the documentation [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/).

---

Your easiest option is **2**, using `@expo/vector-icons`. You don't need to install anything to use them.

Just add the following import to your component

```
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';
```

Then in your render you can use them in the following way:

```
<AntDesign name="stepforward" size={32} color="green" />
```

Making sure to check that the icon you want is available [in the directory](https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/)

---

If you want to preload your font. The font object is available as a static property on the font component, so in the case above it is AntDesign.font, which should evaluate to something like `{antdesign: require('path/to/antdesign.ttf')}`

The documentation on [fonts](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/) and [icons](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons/) on the Expo website is full of great examples.

Comment: Hi, will it work by importing fonts from expo and expo-font and setting up the theme provider? the instruction was below the line of "If you are using expo please make sure fonts has been loaded"  https://rn.mobile.ant.design/docs/react/introduce

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Expo's instructions for installing fonts are quite clear. There are links to the documentation at the bottom of my answer. If you are having difficulties installing the fonts or getting them working then I would suggest you write the relevant parts into a new question so that you can clearly express everything that you need to do, as the comments on SO do not really allow a detailed discussion to take place. For one, code does not format nicely here; and secondly, you are limited to 600 characters, so it makes it hard to express oneself fully